# Why does the 737-300 outflow valve indicator give different readings?

Tags: cabin-pressure

The 737-300 outflow valve opens and closes in manual mode under AC or DC side. While in DC, the indicator is accurate, but when it's in AC mode it reads open when closed.

Does the outflow valve have separate potentiometers for indicating both AC and DC?

Comment: Welcome to [aviation.se]. Could you clarify - is this a theoretical problem, is it a problem you've actually seen in an aircraft you've flown, are you an A&P trying to resolve this issue? You can [edit] your question to include this info. After you've done that, take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with how this forum works, since it's a bit different than a run-of-the-mill discussion board.